# Use a specific web.config when running asp.net mvc on local PC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I added a configuration to my asp.net mvc application called `Release-UK`. This created a `Web.Release-UK.config` file as well.

When I run the application on the local machine, it does not use this configuration. It looks like it is using the `Web.config`, even though the active configuration is `Release-UK`

[image]

How can I tell VS 2015 to use the `Web.Release-UK.config` file when running the application?

Answer (score 0):

We use Transforms in our deployments to set different web.config values for different environments. Here are some articles to get started:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd465318(v=vs.100).aspx

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-forms/overview/deployment/visual-studio-web-deployment/web-config-transformations

Comment: Yes, I am also using Transforms for different deploys. However, how do I test a specific web.config on the local pc from VS?

Comment: I just keeping a set of web.config files somewhere to switch out not an option?